# how to use pos tag as feature in Stanford NER training?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to use the useTags and related features in training Stanford NER CRF model. However, although I have specified in the .prop file that I will use this feature, CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class does not seem to return anything and hence the training does not use this feature at all. Is there something I did wrong that it wasn't using this feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which column in your training/test data has the pos tag and add the pos tags to the CoNLL.

You specify that column in this part of the properties:

`map = word=0,answer=1,tag=2`

(for example if you added the tags in the 3rd column)

Comment: A following up question: So after I train a classifier with the data in such format, how do I call the classifier on a sentence as a String? Do i need to transform that sentence into a format with the tag in it, or is there any way to automatically tag that sentence and use the tags as features when I do classification?

Comment: If you run a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline it should use the POS tag sequence the pipeline tags the sentence with.  Command line info: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html ... NER annotator info: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html ... note you will need to supply your new ner model with an option like this: "-ner.model /path/to/new_model.ser.gz"

Comment: Thanks so much! I am calling the API in a java program. So can I set the properties to include pos, and then set ner.model? And then when I call pipeline.annotate(document), will the pos tag serve as a feature for the ner.model?

Comment: Yes I believe so.